# Why does BITS require netprofm?

Tags: windows-10, services, dependencies

The BITS service (Background Intelligent Transfer service) does not start (error 0x80070422) if netprofm (Network List service) is not running, even though the latter is *not* listed as a dependent service. Question: Why? Under Windows 7, the latter was not essential to start BITS. I'm running as few services as possible, so I'd at least like to understand the reason for this (possible) necessity. I didn't find an explanation anywhere.

Comment: when I use ProcessExplorer to look at the properties of the BITS service I only see RpcSs dependency

Comment: That's the part I already know. Though it doesn't start if the Network List Service is not running.